# Is there a simple way to load extra packages to ghci when invoked via cabal repl?

Tags: haskell, cabal, ghc-pkg

`cabal repl` is quite useful for debugging a library, however ghci will have all packages hidden that aren't dependencies of the cabal package. While that is certainly a good thing for `cabal build`, for `repl` it means I can't load something from an unrelated package for a quick test.

I *can* access any package by issuing `:set -package`, but that'll unload all modules from the pacakge I'm working on, defeating the point of `cabal repl`.

What's a nice way to simply load packages I have installed, but don't want as dependencies to my library?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
cabal repl --ghc-option='-package xyz'
```

This will load the package you are calling `cabal repl` from and the package `xyz`.

To do that after the fact, i.e. when you're already in the REPL and want to load an extra helper module from another package:

```
GHCi> :set -package xyz
GHCi> :m +XYZ.Module.You.Suddenly.Need
```

Comment: Could you also specify a path to a local package, or a git url?

Comment: 1) `cabal repl` (I actually used `cabal new-repl` in the hope it works similarly) tried rebuilding (and failed); 2) `:set -package` unloaded the modules from the current package, as the OP mentioned, and I don't see how to get them back :(

Comment: "cabal repl --ghc-option='-package xyz' seems no longer work for ghci 8.10.7.

Answer (score 10):

When I needed QuickCheck library in scope of ghci I tried

```
cabal repl --ghc-option='-package QuickCheck'
```

and it didn't work at all.

The following saved my day

```
cabal repl --build-depends "QuickCheck >= 2.14"
```

Answer (score 3):

This is only tangential. I searched for how to do with `stack repl`. With Stack you do:

```
stack repl --package xyz
```

Here `repl` is synonymous with `ghci`.

Answer (score 2):

One way (not optimal though) would be to modify your cabal file and add a manual/false flag `extra_dependency`, add the dependencies you need  in a conditional `build-depends` section.

The problem indeed, is you need to manually edit the cabal file each you want to access an `hidden` library but at least, you library doesn't depend officially on those libraries.

Otherwise, you might be able to set the module path to look into your sandbox cache.